# visual studio code task build 'C:\Program' is not recognized

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code

So I am using Visual Studio Code to build and run a simple C++ program. I used the tasks.json to handle compilation: (based off of this: [How to compile C++ code with VS Code and cl](https://www.40tude.fr/blog/how-to-compile-cpp-code-with-vscode-cl/)

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cl",
            "args": [
                "/MDd",
                "/W4",
                "/EHsc",
                "/ZI",
                "/std:c++11",
                "/Od",
                "/Fe:${workspaceFolder}/Debug/test.exe",
                "/Fd:${workspaceFolder}/Debug/",
                "/Fo:${workspaceFolder}/Debug/",
                "main.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Build Release",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cl",
            "args": [
                "/MD",
                "/W4",
                "/EHsc",
                "/std:c++11",
                "/O2",
                "/Fe:${workspaceFolder}/Release/test.exe",
                "/Fd:${workspaceFolder}/Release/",
                "/Fo:${workspaceFolder}/Release/",
                "main.cpp"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try to build I get the following output:

```
 Executing task: cl /MDd /W4 /EHsc /ZI /std:c++11 /Od "/Fe:G:\My Drive\Semester 3\CS 341\Project\Project 2/Debug/test.exe" "/Fd:G:\My Drive\Semester 3\CS 341\Project\Project 2/Debug/" "/Fo:G:\My Drive\Semester 3\CS 341\Project\Project 2/Debug/" main.cpp <

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I will note, I did change the settings in the following way:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat"
    ],
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

I believe that is where the "C:\Program" is coming from. 
I just want to build and execute C++ programs in Visual Studio, so some help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
So I decided to add `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build`to the PATH variable, and then I changed the settings to:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k",
        "vcvars64.bat",
    ],
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

That caused the error to become:

```
> Executing task: cl /MDd /W4 /EHsc /ZI /std:c++11 /Od "/Fe:G:\My Drive\Semester 3\CS 341\Project\Project 2/Debug/test.exe" "/Fd:G:\My Drive\Semester 3\CS 341\Project\Project 2/Debug/" "/Fo:G:\My Drive\Semester 3\CS 341\Project\Project 2/Debug/" main.cpp <

[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : /d
[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : /c
[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : cl
[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : /MDd
[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : /W4
[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : /EHsc
[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : /ZI
[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : /std:c++11
[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : /Od
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to figure out how to pass spaces in the file path. Or just use the "short" path name like in the old 8.3 days.

Comment: never saw the need to do that, since the changes in the settings worked. What would you recommend I do?

Comment: `"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat\""`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I don't use Windows unless I have to -- I'm a Unix person. I was just chiming in on what the problem appears to be. But again, without just exploring it myself I really have no idea. Maybe try putting escaped quotes around the entire path? Something like "terminal.integrated....." ... "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mic.....vcvars64.bat\"". Or maybe escaping the space in the path would work?

Comment: "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat\"" gives the following error: '\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with spaces and parentheses could be solved with the **escape character** which is the caret (`^`) in this case. Using the mentioned character the relevant rows in your `settings.json` would look like:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "/k",
    "C:\\Program^ Files^ ^(x86^)\\Microsoft^ Visual^ Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat"
],
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

The problem with this approach is the same you've encountered when you added the path of `vcvars64.bat` to the `PATH` variable, i.e. Visual Studio Code will **append** the values of `"command"` and `"args"` from your `tasks.json` prefixed with `/d` and `/c` to the value of `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows"` when executing your tasks. This results in that the `vcvars64.bat` will get the mentioned values as arguments not the `cmd.exe`. The errors labeled with `[ERROR:vcvarsall.bat]` appears because the rejection of arguments appended to the wrong place.

You can solve this issue by specifying a shell with appropriate arguments to your tasks as follows:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "options": {
        "shell": {
            "executable": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
            "args": [
                "/d", "/c",
                "C:\\Program^ Files^ ^(x86^)\\Microsoft^ Visual^ Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat",
                "&&"
            ]
        }
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cl",
            "args": [
                "/MDd",
                "/W4",
                "/EHsc",
                "/ZI",
                "/std:c++11",
                "/Od",
                "/Fe:${workspaceFolder}/Debug/test.exe",
                "/Fd:${workspaceFolder}/Debug/",
                "/Fo:${workspaceFolder}/Debug/",
                "main.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Build Release",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cl",
            "args": [
                "/MD",
                "/W4",
                "/EHsc",
                "/std:c++11",
                "/O2",
                "/Fe:${workspaceFolder}/Release/test.exe",
                "/Fd:${workspaceFolder}/Release/",
                "/Fo:${workspaceFolder}/Release/",
                "main.cpp"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Another approach is to leave the `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows"` empty, i.e. don't pass any arguments to the `cmd.exe` in the `settings.json`, then change your `tasks.json` as follows:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "options": {
        "env": {
            "build": "C:\\Program^ Files^ ^(x86^)\\Microsoft^ Visual^ Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat && cl"
        }
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "%build%",
            "args": [
                "/MDd",
                "/W4",
                "/EHsc",
                "/ZI",
                "/std:c++11",
                "/Od",
                "/Fe:${workspaceFolder}/Debug/test.exe",
                "/Fd:${workspaceFolder}/Debug/",
                "/Fo:${workspaceFolder}/Debug/",
                "main.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Build Release",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "%build%",
            "args": [
                "/MD",
                "/W4",
                "/EHsc",
                "/std:c++11",
                "/O2",
                "/Fe:${workspaceFolder}/Release/test.exe",
                "/Fd:${workspaceFolder}/Release/",
                "/Fo:${workspaceFolder}/Release/",
                "main.cpp"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The necessity of calling the `vcvars64.bat` before every build can be omitted if you start Visual Studio Code from the Developer Command Prompt of Visual Studio. For convenience, you can create a shortcut with the following tartget:

```
cmd /d /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" && start /b code
```

This will leave the Developer Command Prompt open which can be closed on demand.

Answer (score 2):

The space in folder name breaks the prompt so in your settings.json file make sure you update the path "Program Files" to simply "PROGRA~1" instead

e.g when i changed

```
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\JDK\\11" to
"java.home": "C:\\PROGRA~1\\JDK\\11"
```

It started working

Comment: Nice one, this works perfectly