# 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use VS Code for simple C++ "Hello, World" program, but when I'm trying to run program with VS Code terminal `cl Source.cpp` I got an error:

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [visual studio code task build 'C:\Program' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459661/visual-studio-code-task-build-c-program-is-not-recognized)

Comment: Did you check if the path to your "cl" command is in your %PATH% ambient variable?

Comment: Are you sure you have the cl compiler? If you have the cl compiler odds are good you have Visual Studio. Why not use Visual Studio?

Comment: You could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800361/cl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).