# Change path for git bash terminal in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

When I use a git bash terminal in VSCode, I get the error

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.

That's because the default path for git bash is C:\Program Files... (see pic bellow)

I tried to install a portable Git to the folder without spaces and then in VSCode to change a git path, but it didn't change the path for git bash. Also, I tried to add the "path" parameter in a settings.json, but it looks like the predefined terminals use the default path, not the custom ones defined in the settings.

```
        "Git Bash": {
            "path": "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\Git\\bin\\Bash.exe"
        }
```

How can I set the custom path for the git bash terminal?

[Terminal path pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyZHf.png)

Comment: Try `"path": "\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\Bash.exe\" --login -i"`

Answer (score 0):

To change the installation path of Git Bash, try renaming `"Git Bash"` to `"Git_Bash"`. VS Code seems to prefer the default path over any customized path for Git Bash due to a bug. I installed Git under `D:\Program Files`, so I did this:

```json
{
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git_Bash",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Git_Bash": {
      "path": "D:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This added a new terminal option, but I still get this error. That's odd, it means that the problem is not in the git bash path, but somewhere else.
My project is in the folder without spaces. Might it be related to the VSCode home folder itself? Or can I somehow check what is that error exactly about?

Comment: Perhaps try looking at “Log (Pty Host)” in the Output panel (View → Output)

Comment: No, all outputs including Pty Host are empty after I get this C:\Program error :( That's really an annoying and odd issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case what helped me was to change git.path in settings.json

1. Press CTRL+SHIFT+P
2. Type *Open Settings*
3. Choose Preferences: Open User
   Settings (JSON)
4. Change git.path parameter to that

   "git.path": "C:\\PROGRA~1\\Git\\bin\\git.exe",

The explanation found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68078670/20276023):

> The space in folder name breaks the prompt so in your settings.json
> file make sure you update the path "Program Files" to simply
> "PROGRA~1" instead